# Unity does not read values from the Serial port correctly, help please

Tags: unity-game-engine, serial-port

I am connecting an Arduino to the Unity game engine and I need them to communicate through the serial ports but for some reason, Unity does not read the data correctly and instead gives me random values between 0 and 300. this is only the problem with Unity since the Arduino IDE's serial monitor reads everything correctly. I am not sure if this is the right forum to ask but nobody ever replied to my question on the Unity forum

here is code from Unity :)

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class UIcontroler : MonoBehaviour
{
    SerialPort data_stream = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
    public string receivedstring;
    public string[] datas;
    public Text text;

    void Start()
    {
        data_stream.Open();
        data_stream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        receivedstring = data_stream.ReadLine();
        text.text = receivedstring;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are sent as a string and have line feeds? Waiting for a line in update could lead to interesting frame rates if there is no data. What exactly are you getting. What are you expecting.

Comment: _"is my question so obvious that nobody wants to answer :("_ - patience good sir.  You only allowed for half-an-hour over what was the weekend for some.  In any event, consider using event-driven serial port rather than the blocking API or placing it in Unity Jobs.   Reading from a serial port directly in `Update()` will slow down your game.  Good luck!

Comment: you will want to get into async/mulithreaded coding for this ... you surely will not ant to freeze your entire app (and also Unity Editor itself) while stuck on waiting for a line ;)

Comment: Have you tried using ARDUnity? It has free version on AssetStore which is very powerful, I've managed to make "game machine" for my apk in just few days.

Comment: well I am supposed to receive the potentiometer value and I have mapped it between 0 and 300 but what I am seeing is a number gradually going between 0 and 300, sometimes getting stuck on random numbers. another thing is that all this worked on my friends laptop but unfortunately its not mine so i don't get to keep it

Comment: No i have not tried ARDUnity because I want to understand how serial communication works in the first place. but if it will get hard i might just have to use it

Comment: I am thinking if you all have been talking about frame rates it might mean that there is a delay with the entire code and i am just getting the correct values after a long delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually what I had to do was put a delay of around 10ms  in my void Update() on the Arduino code